# using the findstr command

Tags: windows, command-line, find

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dispaying part of a file with the fndstr command](https://superuser.com/questions/213538/dispaying-part-of-a-file-with-the-fndstr-command)

I just want to find these two words "hello there" in all directories and all files in my a: using the command prompt format (findstr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
findstr /s /i /c:"hello there" a:\
```

Comment: thanks I got the answer correct on an online practice sheet but could not get it to be displayed on the screen

Comment: how come i cannot see the output of this command. It Is a correct answer but i am just not getting the output?

Comment: You sure you have some files in `a:` ? Unless you have a floppy, I doubt there will be any files.

Comment: it's a usb drive. I type dir and all my files come up. I actually know that 1 file is about the "New York" Yankees. Could be a screwed up usb drive ?

Comment: Seems more like a problem with the the command.

Comment: could it be it doesn't work in windows vista?